# MySQL - Replacing line breaks in Italian text block

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I have a large amount of Italian text copy-pasted from a PDF into MySQL, and the original had line breaks throughout.
So I need to replace, ex:

```
il mer- cante belga
```

with

```
il mercante belga
```

As I don't know how to do such a generic `search/replace` in MySQL I have dumped the data in order to do it in **PHP**, however I can find the instances OK:

```
%s/[a-z]- [a-z]/[a-z][a-z]/gc
```

but replacing like that you just end up with

```
il mer[a-z][a-z]cante belga
```

so any suggestions (either in MySQL or PHP) welcome

Tim

Answer (score 0):

`$sanatizedString = str_replace('- ', '', $oldString);` should do.
I don't see where there would be `-[space]` that you don't what to replace.
However if you want to make sure, there are letters before and after that combo you could go for regex: `\w- \w` (http://regexr.com/39fad) and go for preg_replace.

Answer (score 0):

Using php function [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), searching for pattern `"- "`:

```
$string = "il mer- cante belga";
echo preg_replace('/-\s+/', '', $string);
```

return:

```
il mercante belga
```

where '/-\s+/' match whitespaces (space, tab, newline)

Answer (score 0):

**The issue:**
How to fix a block of Italian text saved in a MySQL DB with line breaks, so for example:

affront- are -> affontare

stilisti- ca -> stilistica

Alma- Tadema -> Alma- Tadema ( unchanged )

Agrippina - madre -> Agrippina - madre ( unchanged )

I resolved this by running a PHP script which processed each instance. The trick is that the only condition is [lowercase letter][hyphen][space][lowercase letter] and isolating this condition ensures a correct revision.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [ the table ] WHERE [ there is an Italian text block with an id ] AND [ it is the unrevised version of the panel ]";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    $id = $row->id; $string = $row->panel;

    $x = 0;

    $y = strlen($string);

    $newstring = '';

    while ($x < $y) {

        if ($string[$x] == '-' && $string[$x+1]==' ') {
            if (!ctype_lower($string[$x-1])) {  } // exclude
            elseif (!ctype_lower($string[$x+2])) { } // exclude
            else { $x++; }
        }
        else { $newstring.=$string[$x]; }
        $x++;
    }

    $xsql = "INSERT INTO [ the table ] [ the fields ] VALUES ( [ the data ] )";

    if (! $xresult = mysql_query($xsql)) { echo (" $xsql = $xresult <br />"); }
}
```

If you are going to try this at home, a word of advice. INSERT the changes into the DB as new records and delete the old records afterwards, or you will be in trouble.